# Problemas con arreglos

Tags: c

tengo algunos errores en el siguiente código.

1. Cuando imprimo `actividad[i][j]` dentro de `void actividad_aleatoria` aparecen algunos caracteres extraños.
2. Al imprimir `actividad[i][j]` dentro de `Main` no deja, solo son espacios vacíos. "Donde tengo entendido los arreglos pueden cambiar de valor en memoria sin necesidad de retornar un valor"

Gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DIA 7
#define HORA 15

typedef char cadenaCaracteres[20]; 
cadenaCaracteres actividad[DIA][HORA];

void activad_aleatoria(int actividad[DIA][HORA])
{
    char *actividades_4[]=
    {
        "Clase de la Universidad",
        
        "Ejercicio",
        
        "Comida",
        
        "Descanso o clase de guitarra electrónica",
    };
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i,j,casu;
    for (i = 0; i < DIA; ++i)
    {   
    
        /*casu=rand() % 5;
        actividades[i]=actividades_4[casu];
        printf("\n %s",actividades[i]);*/
        
    
        for (j = 0; j < HORA; ++j)
        {
            casu=rand() % 5;
            actividad[i][j]=actividades_4[casu];
            printf("\n %s",actividad[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void main(void)
{   

    activad_aleatoria(actividad[DIA][HORA]);
    int i,j,k;
    k=0;
    for (i = 0; i < DIA; ++i)
        //printf("\n %s",actividad[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < HORA; ++j)
            printf("\n %s", actividad[i][j]);
    
    
    printf("\n ---------------------------- \n ");
    
    printf(" %d",k);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no entiendo mal, el cometido es que la función `activad_aleatoria()` rellene el array que le pasas como parámetro con una serie de cadenas, y después la función principal imprima los contenidos del array resultante.

Tienes varios errores en tu código.

- El más importante sería la asignación:

  ```
  actividad[i][j]=actividades_4[casu];
  ```

  puesto que lo que tienes a la derecha de la asignación es una cadena (que para el C es e el fondo un puntero a char), mientras que lo que tienes a la izquierda sería una variable de tipo `cadenaCaracteres` que, tal como la tenías definida, es un `char[20]`, es decir un array de caracteres. No puedes asignar a un array una cadena señalada por un puntero. Todo lo más que puedes hacer es *copiar* en el array la cadena señalada por el puntero, usando `strcpy()`.

  Pero creo que en tu caso la cosa se simplifica si defines `cadenaCaracteres` como puntero, pues se evitan los `strcpy()`, ya que si los elementos de `actividad` son de tipo puntero a char, la asignación anterior sí sería válida.

  Por tanto, primera modificación:

  ```
  typedef char *cadenaCaracteres;
  ```
- El siguiente error es la declaración del parámetro que pasas a la función. Tienes puesto  `(int actividad[DIA][HORA])`, pero los elementos de ese array no son de tipo `int`, sino de tipo `cadenaCaracteres`.

  Por tanto, siguiente modificación:

  ```
  void activad_aleatoria(cadenaCaracteres actividad[DIA][HORA])
  ```
- El número aleatorio lo generas con la expresión `casu=rand() % 5` Eso te produce números entre 0 y 4, pero es erróneo ya que si sale el 4, al acceder a `actividades_4[4]` te irías fuera del array, que sólo tiene índices entre 0 y 3.

  Por tanto, siguiente corrección:

  ```
       casu=rand() % 4;
  ```
- Finalmente, otro error importante, es el paso del parámetro cuando llamas a la función desde `main()`. Lo tienes así:

  ```
  activad_aleatoria(actividad[DIA][HORA]);
  ```

  Pero al usar corchetes de ese modo estás accediendo a un elemento en particular de ese array, en concreto al elemento `[7][15]` (pues esos son los valores de DIA y HORA). Para colmo el elemento al que accedes no existe, pues esos índices estarían ya fuera del array. Pero aún si existieran no tiene sentido lo que haces, pues la función recibiría un elemento del array en lugar del "array completo".

  En realidad los arrays se pasan por dirección, por lo que la función espera recibir la dirección de memoria en que está el array. En vez de eso le estarías pasando uno de los punteros almacenados en el array, con resultados imprevisibles (probablemente un *segmentation fault*).

  La sintaxis correcta para pasar un array es poner solamente el nombre del array, sin corchetes detrás. Eso para el compilador representa "la dirección en que comienza el array", que es justo lo que la función espera. Por tanto, la última modificación sería:

  ```
     activad_aleatoria(actividad);
  ```

### Resultado final

El programa completo quedaría así (he eliminado algunos comentarios y he añadido en `main()` el que imprima los índices del array a medida que lo recorre, para ayudar a depuración):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define DIA 7
#define HORA 15

typedef char *cadenaCaracteres; 
cadenaCaracteres actividad[DIA][HORA];

void activad_aleatoria(cadenaCaracteres actividad[DIA][HORA])
{
    char *actividades_4[]=
    {
        "Clase de la Universidad",       
        "Ejercicio",
        "Comida",
        "Descanso o clase de guitarra electrónica",
    };
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i,j,casu;
    for (i = 0; i < DIA; ++i)
    {   
        for (j = 0; j < HORA; ++j)
        {
            casu=rand() % 4;
            actividad[i][j]=actividades_4[casu];
            // printf("\n --- %s",actividad[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{   
    activad_aleatoria(actividad);
    int i,j,k;
    k=0;
    for (i = 0; i < DIA; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < HORA; ++j)
            printf("\n[%d][%d] %s", i, j, actividad[i][j]);   
    printf("\n ---------------------------- \n ");
}
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
[0][0] Clase de la Universidad
[0][1] Comida
[0][2] Ejercicio
[0][3] Clase de la Universidad
[0][4] Descanso o clase de guitarra electrónica
[0][5] Clase de la Universidad
...
[6][11] Ejercicio
[6][12] Comida
[6][13] Ejercicio
[6][14] Descanso o clase de guitarra electrónica
```

Comment: Me has quitado la palabra de la boca por medio minuto :)

Comment: @eferion Lo siento, nos pasa mucho :-) Igual sí que era necesario algún tipo de indicativo de que alguien está respondiendo a la pregunta, para evitar estas cosas

Comment: No pasa nada ... son gafes del oficio. Lo del aviso yo no lo veo bien porque lo normal es que cada uno le de su enfoque a la pregunta y ene se caso se desincentivaría a la hora de responder

Comment: Gracias bro, son pequeños errores que pase por alto.